# How do I increment a global variable in PHP based on sql database value for a row?

Tags: php, sql

I am having issues incrementing a variable based on one database value output.

OUTPUT EXAMPLE:

[image: Output]

Suppose I have $guest = 0; and $intruder = 0;,  My database values are populated based on sensors on an arduino board and I am working off of a raspberry pi php file.  The output on the page works and here is the code for database values (I limit the latest output 1 at a time.):

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  $request = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
  $statement = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO motion (reading_value, person,lightlevel,lightden) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
  $statement->bind_param("issi", $request->reading_val, $request->person, $request->lightlevel, $request->lightden);

  $statement->execute();
  die();
}

$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM motion ORDER BY reading_id DESC LIMIT 1");
$statement->execute();
$statement->bind_result( $reading_id, $reading_value, $person, $lightlevel, $lightden, $time_detected);
```

and as of now this is my fetch loop to echo the output:

```
while($statement->fetch()) {
    $time_parts = explode(" ",$time_detected);
    $time = date("h:i:sa", strtotime($time_parts[1]));
    echo "ID: {$reading_id} </br>  Reading Value:  {$reading_value} </br>  Time: {$time} </br>  Person: {$person} </br> Lightlevel: {$lightlevel} </br> Lightden:>
    
    echo "<tr><td>" . $person .  "&nbsp; </td><td>" . $time . "</td></tr> </br>";
    
    if ($person == "Guest") {
        ++$guest;
    } else { 
        ++$intruder;
    }
}
    
echo "<tr>Guest Counter: &nbsp<td>" . $guest .  "&nbsp;</td>Intruder Counter: &nbsp<td>" . $intruder . "</td></tr>";
```

I tried placing my if statement in and out of the loop, but it increments once but no more.

What I need is if the $person variable is "Guest", increment the global variable `$guest` by one and if it outputs "Intruder" for $person, I need $intruder incremented by one.

I feel like it is a simple mistake, but idk what is the issue.  I genuinely checked out other sites and some documentation but I can't find the answer specifically for my issue.

Comment: You have `LIMIT 1` in the query. So it only returns one person, and the counter just counts whether that person is a guest or intruder.

Comment: I tried changing the limit but it didn't change anything.  The page auto refreshes for the latest entry because the data is sent live from arduino to rasp pi.

Comment: If you want to get the total count without printing all of them, do a separate query. `SELECT SUM(person='Guest') AS guestcount, SUM(person != 'Guest') AS intrudercount FROM motion`

Comment: Gotcha appreciate it boss.